# How to build custom bootstrap bundle using Rollup

Tags: javascript, rollup, bootstrap-5

According to Bootstrap 5 official documentation, we can import pre-compiled js files from `bootstrap/js/dist` and build a custom bundle using (Webpack, rollup, ...).

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/#individual-or-compiled

And in the optimizing section in docs, they gave an example of how you can import js files.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize/#lean-javascript

**The problem:**
I created a file named `bootstrap.js`

```
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip';
```

and I want only to use the `Tooltip` plugin.
I use the below configuration for rollup

```
  const plugins = [
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      // Include the helpers in each file, at most one copy of each
      babelHelpers: 'bundled',
      presets: [
        [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          {
            loose: true,
            bugfixes: true,
            modules: false
          }
        ]
      ]
    }),
    nodeResolve()
  ]

  const bundle = await rollup.rollup({
    input: './js/vendors/bootstrap.js',
    plugins,
  })

  await bundle.write({
    format: 'umd',
    file: './file.js'
  })
```

After generating the `file.js` and use an HTML page an error  shows up in the console `file.js:1727 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`

Also I can't use bootstrap syntax to initialize the `Tooltip` plugin
`new bootstrap.Tooltip` gives an error of undefined `bootstrap`.

I can achieve what I want by import these files from `js/src` folder and export them as they use in `js/src/index.umd.js` but following bootstrap official documentation on how to import their plugin seems not to work properly.

Comment: I suspect that your problem isn't specific to bootstrap, and has more to do with the rollup config not being set up for a browser. For example, nodeResolve should be configured with `browser: true` https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-node-resolve. Likewise, you should check your babel config. If you need more help, consider sharing a more complete example.

Answer (score 3):

**Documentation error**

While this is not the answer you want, it does seem that the correct answer is, "Bootstrap's documentation has an error."

For `umd` output, if I import with this syntax:

`import Dropdown from '../../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown';`

the build fails with the following error:

`Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules\bootstrap\js\dist\dropdown.js, imported by src\js\bootstrap-build.js`

Which is contrary to this: [Files in bootstrap/js/dist use the default export,](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize/#lean-javascript).

**What does work (includes Popper):**

To the reader, assuming you came here to find a solution to a build problem you are having, below is what works for me.

This answer assumes all dependencies were installed using NPM as a dev dependency except for Bootstrap 5, which was installed with this command:

`npm install bootstrap`

This is *rollup.config.js*:

```js
import {terser} from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

export default {
    input: './src/js/bootstrap-build.js',
    output: {
        file: 'dist/js/bootstrap.umd.min.js',
        format: "umd",
        name: "bsbundle", // this is the name of the global object
        esModule: false,
        sourcemap: true,
    },
    plugins: [terser({compress: {drop_console: true, module: true}})]
};
```

This is the project's entry script, i.e. *bootstrap-build.js*, located in *<project root>/src/js/*:

```js
import * as Popper from '../../node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.js';

// from 'js/src/*' source which works
import Modal from '../../node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/modal';
import Tab from '../../node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/tab';
import Dropdown from '../../node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/dropdown';
import Tooltip from '../../node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/tooltip';

export default {
  // Alert,
  // Button,
  // Carousel,
  // Collapse,
  Dropdown,
  Modal,
  // Offcanvas,
  // Popover,
  // ScrollSpy,
  Tab,
  // Toast,
    // Popper,
  Tooltip
}
```

And the *package.json*:

```json
{
  "name": "bscomponents",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Project for building Bootstrap 5 components.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build-bs": "rollup -c"
    },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-multi-entry": "^4.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "rollup": "^2.60.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
  }
}
```

NPM build command:

`NPM run build-bs`

**Build note:** The line importing *Popper* in the Bootstrap *Dropdown* and *Tooltip* source files is commented out.

Bundle includes *Popper*, *Dropdown*, *Modal*, *Tab*, and *Tooltip*

File *index.html* in project root for testing bundle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap 5 components</title>
    <!-- custom Bootstrap bundle saves about 21kb -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- and a few simple styles -->
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 5rem;
            margin: 1rem auto;
        }

        .btn-wrapper {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 1rem auto;
        }

        .btn-wrapper li {
            padding: 1rem
        }

        .tab-pane {
            padding: 2rem;
        }

        ul {
            margin: 3rem
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>


    <h1>Bootstrap 5 components</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>Dropdown</li>
        <li>Modal (an option in the dropdown)</li>
        <li>Tabs</li>
        <li>Tooltip</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="btn-wrapper dropdown" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="This is a Bootstrap 5 dropdown.">
        <button type="button" id="btnDropDown" class="btn btn-primary btn-calculator dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Options&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnDropDown">
            <li data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#MYMODAL">
                <b>Modal</b>
            </li>
            <li>
                Second option
            </li>
            <li>
                And a final option
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>

        <nav>
            <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-tab-1" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-calc-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-calc-1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</button>
                <button class="nav-link" id="nav-tab-2" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-options-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-options-1" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</button>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent-1">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-calc-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-tab-1">
                <p>tab 1</p>
            </div>
            <!--role="tabpanel"-->

            <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="nav-options-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-tab-2">
                <!-- option tab content -->
                <p>tab 2</p>

            </div>
            <!-- role tabpanel -->

        </div>
        <!--end tab-content-->

    </div>


    <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="MYMODAL">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Before you leave, hover over the below buttons.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Click to close">Seconday</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" title="I do nothing!">Primary</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- end modal -->


    <script src="./dist/js/bootstrap.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
        var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
            return new bsbundle.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Development environment:**

- Windows 10
- Rollup v2.6
- Node v16.10.0
- NPM 8.1.3
- Bootstrap 5.1.3

Build run in VS Code v1.62's Bash terminal.

**The result**:

The build bundle including `Popper`, <project root>/dist/js/bootstrap.umd.min.js, saves about 21kb over Bootstrap's distributed minified bundle.

[Probable documentation issue reported on GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/35352)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to dissect your code - you're missing the whole dependance on Popper.

But this is how I would have done it *(hint: I took the BS5 source code and stripped all the things not wanted.)*

Assuming you're compiling on top of a fork of Boorstrap 5:

*File:* `build\rollup.config.mk.js`:

```js
'use strict'

const path = require('path')
const { babel } = require('@rollup/plugin-babel')
const { nodeResolve } = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve')
const replace = require('@rollup/plugin-replace')
const banner = require('./banner.js')

let fileDest = `bootstrap-mk`
const external = ['@popperjs/core']
const plugins = [
  babel({
    // Only transpile our source code
    exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    // Include the helpers in the bundle, at most one copy of each
    babelHelpers: 'bundled'
  })
]
const globals = {
  '@popperjs/core': 'Popper'
}

const rollupConfig = {
  input: path.resolve(__dirname, `../js/index.mk.umd.js`),
  output: {
    banner,
    file: path.resolve(__dirname, `../dist/js/${fileDest}.js`),
    format: 'umd',
    globals
  },
  external,
  plugins
}

rollupConfig.output.name = 'bootstrap'

module.exports = rollupConfig
```

... and also ...

*File:* `js\index.mk.umd.js`

```js
import Tooltip from './src/tooltip'

export default {
  Tooltip
}
```

Then call:  `rollup --config build/rollup.config.mk.js --sourcemap` from the command line, or add something like this to the `packacge.json` \ "`scripts`" section:

```json
  "js-compile-mk": "rollup --config build/rollup.config.mk.js --sourcemap",
```

... and call `npm run js-compile-mk` from the command line.

Output will be a file called:  `dist\js\bootstrap-mk.js` *(and a map file)*

---

If you want to not use a fork, but rather a `node_modules` sub-folder, then go about changing the paths in the `build\rollup.config.mk.js` file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as mentioned in my question I already achieved to build a custom bootstrap bundle by importing files from `src`, but this is not how the official documentation suggests, So anyway I think bootstrap team is missing something.

Comment: Add this to the issues page: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues .  I doubt the authors look on SO.