# Bootstrap 5 with popper js using rollup compiler

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, rollup

I just want to ask how I can include popper.js in my bootstrap 5 using rollup compiler. Here is my rollup.config.js file . but It always said that "popper is not defined in my browser console . thanks

```js
'use strict'

const path = require('path')
const { babel } = require('@rollup/plugin-babel')
const { nodeResolve } = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve')
import multi from '@rollup/plugin-multi-entry'
const banner = require('./banner.js')

let fileDest = 'child-theme.js'
const external = ['jquery','@popperjs/core']
const plugins = [
  babel({
    // Only transpile our source code
    exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    // Include the helpers in the bundle, at most one copy of each
    babelHelpers: 'bundled'
  }),
  nodeResolve(),
  multi()
]
const globals = {
  jquery: 'jQuery', // Ensure we use jQuery which is always available even in noConflict mode
  '@popperjs/core': 'Popper'
}


module.exports = {
  input: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../js/bootstrap.js'), path.resolve(__dirname, '../js/skip-link-focus-fix.js'), path.resolve(__dirname, '../js/custom-javascript.js')],
  output: {
    banner,
    file: path.resolve(__dirname, `../../js/${fileDest}`),
    format: 'umd',
    globals,
    name: 'understrap'
  },
  external,
  plugins
}
```

Comment: "popper" or "Popper"?

Comment: I won't post this as an answer as it might not strictly fix things for you but.... There are two ways to call Bootstrap 5. One of them includes Popper and one doesn't.

Here are the docs..... 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Hi I already imported the @popper core from the node_modules to my bootstrap.js file using three shaking. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@popperjs/core of @popper/core.

Comment: After I run the dist in CLI I have this  error in my browser console. Popper is not defined and popperInstance is not defined. Here is the sample code where the console defined the error.

 const popperInstance = Popper.createPopper(button, tooltip, {
        modifiers: [
          {
            name: 'offset',
            options: {
              offset: [0, 8],
            },
          },
        ],
      });

Comment: I just posted an answer to a [similar Rollup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67129942/how-to-build-custom-bootstrap-bundle-using-rollup/69957734#69957734). The answer includes how I included `Popper` in the Bootstrap bundle. Hope it helps.